# How to assign predefined lengths to pie slices in a polar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm attempting to make a polar plot, where rather than a spiral I have actual pie slices. So for example, I have a dataset as so:

| Radius | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | hamster |
| 5 | fish |
| 0 | dog |
| 6 | cat |

So, I want to output a plot that had the maximum radius of 6 and minimum of 0 and the width is based on the amount of values (hence for this case it'd be 90 degree per slice). My current code is like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


index= ['A','B','C','D']
columns= ['radius','name']
values= [[4, "hamster"],[5, "fish"],[0, "dog"],[7, "cat"]]
df= pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=columns, dtype= float)
print(df)

# Compute pie slices
N = df.shape[0]

theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
for i in range(0,len(values) - 1):
    radius = df.values[i,0]
    i = i + 1
width = np.pi / 4 * 100
print(width)
colors = plt.cm.viridis(radius / 10.)

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.bar(theta, radius, width=width, bottom=0.0, color=colors, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Currently it outputs a circle as opposed to 4 slices (or in this case 3 as one is of the value 0). I do understand my radius for loop, only takes in the last value in the loop, however whenever I try to turn the radius modifier into a list the whole program goes haywire... I've been going in circles (pun not intended) trying different solutions but I've hit a wall at every step, do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Your loop to calculate `radius` is very strange.  It only stores the last value.  Also, multiplying the width by 100 makes the bar go round the circle many times.  Maybe you could try something like `radius = df['radius'].values; width = 2*np.pi / N`?

Comment: Yeap, clearly need to brush up on my pandas knowledge ha, both of those work a charm. I did reverse your logic by accident but it's just what I needed!